# Generate Dummy Variables From Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a `data.frame` with the following properties:

```
list1 <- c(145540,145560, 157247, 145566)
list2 <- c(166927, NA, NA, NA)
list3 <- c(145592, 145560, 145566, NA)
df <- data.frame(list1, list2, list3)
```

I would like to generate a dummy variables for each of the included ids. The result should look like this.

```
list, 145540, 145560, 145566,145592,157247,166927 (= all possible ids in the data)

list1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0

list2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1

list3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? Thank You!

Comment: Look at `?sample()`.

Comment: you need dummy variables or values? The title is misleading. You need to explain more on the output. 0 and 1 are random or they have some condition

Comment: The goal is to create a data.frame where the value 1 occours if e.g., 145540 is present in a list, else 0. Its not about random sampling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is a little clunkier, but here it is:

```
all.vals <- na.omit(unique(unlist(df)))  ## get full set of values
```

Use a `for` loop for greater clarity:

```
df2 <- list()
for (i in seq_along(df))
  df2[[i]] <-
  sapply(all.vals,
         function(x) as.numeric(x %in% df[[i]]))
names(df2) <- names(df)
## add labels as the first column:
df2 <- data.frame(all.vals,df2)
```

Result:

```
  all.vals list1 list2 list3
1   145540     1     0     0
2   145560     1     0     1
3   157247     1     0     0
4   145566     1     0     1
5   166927     0     1     0
6   145592     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `stack` and `table`:

```
t(table(stack(df)))
##        values
## ind     145540 145560 145566 145592 157247 166927
##   list1      1      1      1      0      1      0
##   list2      0      0      0      0      0      1
##   list3      0      1      1      1      0      0
```

Alternatively, with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
melt(as.data.table(df), measure.vars = names(df), na.rm = TRUE)[
  , dcast(.SD, variable ~ value, fun = length)]
##    variable 145540 145560 145566 145592 157247 166927
## 1:    list1      1      1      1      0      1      0
## 2:    list2      0      0      0      0      0      1
## 3:    list3      0      1      1      1      0      0
```

Or with the "tidyverse":

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(var, col, everything(), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(val = 1) %>% 
  spread(col, val, fill = 0)
```

Or with "qdapTools":

```
mtabulate(df)
```

Comment: How would you solve this problem using a Spark Cluster and for example SparklyR?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%in%`:

```
list %in% list1 + 0
# [1] 1 1 1 0 1 0
```

Note you have a typo in your answer for list1 since 145592 is not in list1 but 157247 is. The `+ 0` converts TRUE/FALSE to 1/0. You can process the whole data frame with `sapply()`:

```
t(sapply(df, function(x) list %in% x + 0))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# list1    1    1    1    0    1    0
# list2    0    0    0    0    0    1
# list3    0    1    1    1    0    0
```